# Webcontrol as a property of another webcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net sometimes a webcontrol needs to reference another webcontrol such as the gridview needs the id of the datasource object that it will bind to.

I have a property of my webcontrol that is a string (the id of the webcontrol I want to reference). How do I access the actual webcontrol based on this id?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.FindControl()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: The FindControl only looks in any given container. But if this the only tool available for this situation, then the solution is to build a recursive method that traverses the page structure and return the control that matches the id provided.

Comment: hmm... but isn't Page.FindControl() searching on the whole page?

Comment: It's not supposed to:
"The FindControl method can be used to access a control whose ID is not available at design time. The method searches only the page's immediate, or top-level, container; it does not recursively search for controls in naming containers contained on the page. To access controls in a subordinate naming container, call the FindControl method of that container." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of a GridView bound to an ObjectDataSource, with the ObjectDataSource binding to a DropDownList for a parameter. This should get you started.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="CustomerObjectDataSource" 
    DataKeyNames="CustomerID"
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
    onrowdeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated">
    <Columns>
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CustomerObjectDataSource" runat="server" 
    EnablePaging="True" 
    MaximumRowsParameterName="totalRows" 
    StartRowIndexParameterName="firstRow" 
    TypeName="Northwind.Business.CustomerSource" 
    DataObjectTypeName="Northwind.Business.CustomerDTO"
    SelectMethod="Load" 
    UpdateMethod="Save" 
    InsertMethod="Insert" 
    DeleteMethod="Delete"
    SelectCountMethod="CustomerCount" 
    SortParameterName="sortExpression">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlRegion" Name="region" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: The question that remains is: Does the gridview locate the ObjectDataSource by traversing the page recursively using the FindControl method?

Comment: @SynBiotik, no. The DataSourceID field of the GridView markup identifies the ObjectDataSource by the data source's ID. The binding is explicit (in the example code above, "CustomerObjectDataSource").

Comment: IHere is the DataSourceId code:
public virtual string DataSourceID
{
    get
    {
        object obj2 = this.ViewState["DataSourceID"];
        if (obj2 != null)
        {
            return (string) obj2;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DataSourceID))
        {
            this._requiresBindToNull = true;
        }
        this.ViewState["DataSourceID"] = value;
        this.OnDataPropertyChanged();
    }
}
How does the gridview tie the string to the actual object ?